# Flutter App built on Xcode version 12.5.1 crashes on iOS 14.7

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter-test

I uploaded an application to AppStore, and it was working fine.
app version 5.0.2
Xcode version 12.5.1

I tried to update the application recently. The app is running fine with the emulator on iOS 15 or 14.5, but we received a 14.8 crash report. We also tested the physical devices on 14.7. It crashes.

app version 5.0.3
Xcode version 12.5.1

Therefore we tried to test the 5.0.2 version on 14.7 (which is the same code), it also crashes. The codebase is basically the same as the one currently on appstore, but it won't run.

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b9481334 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d6f05a9c pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1582)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019465db84 abort + 124 (abort.c:118)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000102b18ed0 0x10282c000 + 3067600
4   Flutter                         0x0000000102b19000 0x10282c000 + 3067904
5   Flutter                         0x0000000102d12508 0x10282c000 + 5137672
6   Flutter                         0x0000000102b7b844 0x10282c000 + 3471428
7   Flutter                         0x000000010283fd20 0x10282c000 + 81184
8   Flutter                         0x0000000102856410 0x10282c000 + 173072
9   Flutter                         0x000000010285624c 0x10282c000 + 172620
10  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d88da70 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2288 (UINib.m:389)
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000018de0cb18 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 284 (UIStoryboard.m:233)
12  UIKitCore                       0x000000018de0c9b0 -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 128 (UIStoryboard.m:212)
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc8c7dc -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 184 (UIApplication.m:4429)
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc8cd14 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 280 (UIApplication.m:0)
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc8b468 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 996 (UIApplication.m:4171)
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2df1a4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 152 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:436)
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d848458 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 104 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2dfd3c __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 224 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:549)
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2df744 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 300 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:498)
20  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2dfb4c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 768 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:548)
21  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2df388 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:454)
22  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2e78cc __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 196 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:72)
23  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d755e84 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:50)
24  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d861268 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 276 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:23)
25  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d2e75c4 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 384 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:57)
26  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d10f4ac __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 776 (UIScene.m:1419)
27  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d10de2c -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256 (UIScene.m:1140)
28  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d10f0d4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 248 (UIScene.m:1386)
29  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc89700 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 572 (UIApplication.m:3697)
30  UIKitCore                       0x000000018d77f4e4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 388 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:45)
31  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a8685d8 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440 (FBSScene.m:435)
32  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a893d44 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.200 + 128 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:365)
33  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a8776a4 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240 (FBSWorkspace.m:355)
34  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a893a0c __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 372 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:364)
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ae8381c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ae8730c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268 (queue.c:468)
37  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a8bbfa0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:184)
38  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a8bbc30 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448 (FBSSerialQueue.m:227)
39  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019a8bc184 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:258)
40  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b210990 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
41  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b21088c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
42  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b20fb90 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
43  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b209b70 __CFRunLoopRun + 820 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
44  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b209308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
45  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a288c734 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
46  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc8775c -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
47  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc8cfcc UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
48  Runner                          0x000000010251f7e0 main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
49  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018aec5cf8 start + 4
```

Comment: Any log like this?: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.

Comment: Try removing ~/.pub-cache and invalidate cache and restart in android studio.

Comment: Also, remove the bin/cache folder from your flutter sdk path and then run flutter doctor. Then do a flutter clean and try a new build.